# Android BottomSheet and dynamic Content

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a bottom sheet, where i can dynamically pass to it the layout id of the layout i want it to show. This works fine! The problem with this is that, to me, it is somewhat cumbersome to assign the listeners I want to every UI element of that layout.

I can also pass the assign a pre-infalted view with all the listeners assigned to a member of the bottomsheet, which also works.

I was wondering if there is a best practice established for this, or any pros/cons in the approaches!

Thanks!

Comment: what's listener your mean? onClick?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, You can define a loop on `ViewGroup` of Inflated and get each of `View` finally define a `onClickListener` and set it on views

```
override fun onViewInflated() {

        viewGroupInflated?.forEach {
            it?.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)
        }
    }


private val onClickListener = View.OnClickListener {
    when(it.id){
        R.id.btn_a -> //Todo an action
        R.id.btn_b -> //Todo an action
    }
}
```